# Maximum value of a function along a curve without Lagrange multipliers.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I want to find the maximum value of a function $f(x,y)$ such that $(x,y)$ lie on $g(x,y)=c$. So I substitue for $x$ from $g(x,y)=c$ in $f(x,y)$ so that it becomes a function of one variable $f(y) (say)$ now I differentiate this wrt $y$ and get the critical points, is that correct?
I could think of this in two ways.

**Approach 1**: As we are differentiating along the $y$ axis and not along the curve we would get incorrect results.

**Approach 2**: If I plot $f(y)$ and $y$ in a $zy$ plane it would be the same as the projection of the curve that we get by intersecting $z=f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)=c$ on the $zy$ plane so differentiating wrt $y$ would give correct results.

Please tell me which approach is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's very rare that you can solve $g(x,y)=c$ explicitly for either variable in terms of the other. But if you have $x=\phi(y)$ and you consider $F(y) = f(\phi(y),y)$, then of course maximizing $F(y)$ is the thing you want to do.

Comment: @Akshat Sharma   Don't forget the domain of $y$ when using the substitution. Otherwise, for the critical points of $f(y)$, there may be no corresponding (real) $x$ satisfying $g(x,y)=c$.